# GitLab still recommended for Salesforce

Tags: salesforcedx, cicd, gitlab

I try to get involved using GitLab in combination with Salesforce. However, the trailhead module  'Build an Automated CI/CD Pipeline with GitLab' seems to have been taken offline, and some other resource links do not function either. However, I still can login using my Salesforce account. Is there any up to date GitLab - Salesforce documents available to get into the topic? How is the current opinion on the topic?

Comment: Tried to grab you a cached version of the trailhead but not even way back machine has it :(

Comment: Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems the specific trailhead you linked has been retired. In terms of Gitlab/Salesforce documentation, it seems the following Salesforce [blog post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/05/gitlab-salesforce-devops-made-easy) related to when that trailhead was created contains many resources

- [SFDX project template for GitLab](https://gitlab.com/sfdx/sfdx-project-template/tree/master) where the [README](https://gitlab.com/sfdx/sfdx-project-template/blob/master/README.md) has a guide to get started with GitLab and Salesforce development.
- [sfdx-cicd-template](https://gitlab.com/sfdx/sfdx-cicd-template) is a project that contains a fully configured CI pipeline following the package development module.
- [SFDX gitlab-ci.yml template](https://gitlab.com/sfdx/sfdx-project-template/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) along with [other templates on Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/sfdx)

There's also this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tylPp9QlLu4) walkthrough (has very low audio) that goes over setting it up as well.

Comment: Yes, these seem to be valuable ressources. I just wondered that there is no recent documentation and discussions available ...